# Iterating over struct members, SystemVerilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, hdl, register-transfer-level

I have a type parameter t, that expects a struct, I then want to; in a generate block, iterate
over each named  field/member in said struct to generate some code:

```
typedef struct packed {
   bit       a,
   bit[7:0]  b,
   bit[15:0] c
};

module x #(
  parameter type t = my_struct;
)

generate
  // where here "my_struct[m]" is an individual struct field, not each bit individually.
  foreach(my_struct[m]) begin
    //...
  end
endgenerate
```

Is there anyway to this?

Comment: you can iterate over bits, since this is a packed struct, but not over fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Structs are objects for individual field selection. Arrays are objects for iteration.

There is no way to do this within the SystemVerilog language. There are ways to iterate over fields of a struct using the Verilog Programming interface  (VPI) in C code, but that certainly would not be synthesizable.

You could use the `let` construct or a `` `define `` macro to make it easy to create repetitive code.